# GET JSON Object from extern url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I am programming with JavaScript and i have API which is giving me an JSON Object.
This is the ->http://193.70.60.44:3000/geoserver/taxi_server/api/v1.0/taxi object url.

In this JSON object there is   JSONOBJECT.position.coordinates[0] which is giving me the longitude of an position.

How can i get the JSON object in javascript and use the coordinates?

Comment: Your api gives response : `{"message":"Welcome to the beginning of nothingness."}`

Comment: The posted URL has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and it's not JSONP, so there's no way to get that JSON in a browser directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this using jQuery (edited), but using the the proper properties in your returned object:

```
var myUrl = 'http://siteofjson.org/getjson/';
$.getJSON(myUrl, function(JSONOBJECT){
   console.log(JSONOBJECT.position.coordinates[0]);
   var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(JSONOBJECT.position.coordinates[0].lon,JSONOBJECT.position.coordinates[0].lat)
        .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // Transformation aus dem Koordinatensystem WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // in das Koordinatensystem 'Spherical Mercator Projection'
        );
});
```